# Getting rid of the 0 value in MIN function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to get the minimum value in a range excluding the 0's.

```
Cells(PoleRow, 4).Formula = "=MIN(IF($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$<>0" & PoleRow & "))"
```

I am not sure if I have the <>0 in the right place or not. I always thought that it should be placed after the column_num.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it is in the wrong place and you want to use `FormulaArray` and you need to return something with the IF:

```
 Cells(PoleRow, 4).FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & "<>0,$AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & "))"
```

Comment: getting Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the range class unfortunately... @ScottCraner